# Javascript fundamentals: negative values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I know this may be too simple for most people here, but I'm starting to learn Javascript and I'm stuck in this - apparently - very simple challenge: I'm supposed to write a function that counts the number of negative values in an array. This is what I wrote:

```
function myFunction(a) {
let n = 0;
for (let x = 0; x =< a.length; x++) {
 if (a[x] < 0) {n++}; 
 else {n = n};

return n
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong with it but tests keep coming wrong, I have tried changing it all over but nothing works. Any ideas as to what I did wrong?

Comment: `x =< a.length` -> `x < a.length`

Answer (score -1):

Remove the else part in your code and move your return statement outside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks, worked! I also had to change x =< a.length -> x < a.length